# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined (React + Contentful)

Tags: reactjs, contentful

I'm trying to create a "portfolio" website to learn react. I've plugged content from Contentul, but i'm getting an error : `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined` when trying to display my content.

Here's what i've done so far to get content from Contentful into my React app :

1. I've creacted a contentful.js file

```js
## contentful.js

const client = require('contentful').createClient({
  space: 'MYSPACEID',
  accessToken: 'MYACCESSTOKEN',
});

const getProjectItems = () => client.getEntries().then((response) => response.items);

const getSingleProject = (slug) =>
  client
    .getEntries({
      'fields.slug': slug,
      content_type: 'project',
    })
    .then((response) => response.items);

export { getProjectItems, getSingleProject };
```

Then, i've created 2 custom Hooks for getting my content :

```js
## UseProjects.js

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { getProjectItems } from '../contentful';

const promise = getProjectItems();

export default function useProjects() {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    promise.then((project) => {
      setProjects(project);
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }, []);

  return [projects, isLoading];
}
```

```
## useSingleProject.js

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { getSingleProject } from '../contentful';

export default function useSingleProject(slug) {
  const promise = getSingleProject(slug);

  const [project, setProject] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    promise.then((result) => {
      setProject(result[0].fields);
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }, [promise]);

  return [project, isLoading];
}
```

I can add my components code if needed but i feel like my error comes from here.. What's weird is that if i close the error, i see all the items properly rendered (so..they're properly pulled from Contentful) and if i click on it i've got the correct informations displayed (title, image, etc.). But the error makes weird layout things.

The error comes from my useSingleProject.js file (`useSingleProject.js:13`)

Now here i feel it can also come from my App.js file, i'm not sure about how i configured the routing for single project pages (i'm still new to react..). If i disable the following line from the `routes` array : `{ path: '/:id', name: ':id', Component: SingleProject }`, then the error disapears. I can see all the projects on my projects page, but if i click on one of them the slug changes but nothing shows on the single project pages, since i've disabled it.

```js
## App.js

import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { gsap } from 'gsap';
import './styles/App.scss';
import Header from './components/header';
import Navigation from './components/navigation';

import CaseStudies from './pages/caseStudies';
import Approach from './pages/approach';
import Services from './pages/services';
import About from './pages/about';
import Home from './pages/home';
import Projects from './pages/projects';
import SingleProject from './pages/SingleProject';

const routes = [
  { path: '/', name: 'Home', Component: Home },
  { path: '/case-studies', name: 'caseStudies', Component: CaseStudies },
  { path: '/approach', name: 'approach', Component: Approach },
  { path: '/services', name: 'services', Component: Services },
  { path: '/about-us', name: 'about', Component: About },
  { path: '/projects', name: 'projects', Component: Projects },
  { path: '/:id', name: ':id', Component: SingleProject },
];

function debounce(fn, ms) {
  let timer;
  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      timer = null;
      fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }, ms);
  };
}

function App() {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = React.useState({
    height: window.innerHeight,
    width: window.innerWidth,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // prevents flashing
    gsap.to('body', 0, { css: { visibility: 'visible' } });
    const debouncedHandleResize = debounce(function handleResize() {
      setDimensions({
        height: window.innerHeight,
        width: window.innerWidth,
      });
    }, 1000);

    window.addEventListener('resize', debouncedHandleResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', debouncedHandleResize);
    };
  });
  return (
    <>
      <Header dimensions={dimensions} />
      <div className="App">
        {routes.map(({ path, Component }) => (
          <Route key={path} exact path={path}>
            <Component dimensions={dimensions} />
          </Route>
        ))}
      </div>
      <Navigation />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**EDIT :** 
So i've tried to `console.log(response.items)` in my getSingleProject function. It returns the correct array of object (so here containing only one object).

I've also tried tu `console.log(result)` in my useProjects function (inside the useEffect). It still logs the correct object, and it has the fields property i need to get. When console logging in my useEffect, it logs the object every second or so by the way. Is this a normal behavior?

Comment: `result[0]` is `undefined` which in turn means that `response.items` in `getSingleProject` is `undefined`. Put a `debugger` or a `console.log`, and check what `response` is, make sure it is returning what you expect it to return.

Comment: @nicooga when `console.log(response.items)` in my getSingleProject function, it returns the object nicely but it stays on loading. It looks like it's endlessly trying to get the data. Isn't my error coming from my Routes? When disabling ` { path: '/:id', name: ':id', Component: SingleProject }` from my routes variables, the error disappear

Comment: Your code expects `response.items` to be an array, where the first element is a nobject that has a `fields` property (`[{ fields: ... }]`). Is it? You can also try checking the value of `result` in your `useEffect`.

Comment: @nicooga Actually yes it returns an array of object, and the object (here 0) contains a field property with all the correct infos from contentful.. I've tried to add a `console.log(result)` in my useEffect, it returns the same good object with the correct infos (it logs it again every second btw, it logged it 1K times in a few seconds.. normal behavior?)

Comment: I think your hook `useSingleProject` is coded in a way that causes an infinite render loop. Let me expand on that.

Answer (score 0):

Your hook `useSingleProject` is coded in such a way that it triggers an infinite re-render loop. Here is a reproduction of the behaviour I describe: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-banach-tr609?file=/src/index.js. Observe how the console logs forever.

This happens because the hook `useSingleProject` is going to be called on each re-render, creating a new promise each time. In turn `useEffect` will trigger when `promise` is changed, causing an eventual state update, which also means an eventual re-render. This causes an infinite loop.

The solution would be to make your effect to depend on `slug` instead of `promise`. In fact, you don't even need to assign the promise to a variable first.

Also, just in case, it makes sense to only set `isLoading` to true only if you actually had to fetch data. So:

```
export default function useSingleProject(slug) {
  const [project, setProject] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)

    getSingleProject(slug).then((result) => {
      setProject(result[0].fields);
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }, [slug]);

  return [project, isLoading];
}
```

Comment: Doing so i get a new error saying that my fields doesn't exist (`cannot read property X of null` => the object is not returned anymore as it was before)

Comment: You need to triple check what `getSinleProject`'s promise resolves to. There's a chance that the 3rd party service returns something unexpected, and your code needs to deal with that edge-case.

Answer (score 0):

So after another day trying to understand where the error comes from, it looks like it's coming from the way i've setup my `Router` in `App.js`. By modifying it, the error disappeared and now all content is pulled and displayed correctly. For those interested, here is my new `App.js` file and how i've setup routes for now to correct the issue :

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { gsap } from 'gsap';
import './styles/App.scss';
import Header from './components/header';
import Navigation from './components/navigation';

import Approach from './pages/approach';
import Services from './pages/services';
import About from './pages/about';
import Home from './pages/home';
import Projects from './pages/projects';
import SingleProject from './pages/SingleProject';

function debounce(fn, ms) {
  let timer;
  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      timer = null;
      fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }, ms);
  };
}

function App() {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = React.useState({
    height: window.innerHeight,
    width: window.innerWidth,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // prevents flashing
    gsap.to('body', 0, { css: { visibility: 'visible' } });
    const debouncedHandleResize = debounce(function handleResize() {
      setDimensions({
        height: window.innerHeight,
        width: window.innerWidth,
      });
    }, 1000);

    window.addEventListener('resize', debouncedHandleResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', debouncedHandleResize);
    };
  });
  return (
    <>
      <Header dimensions={dimensions} />
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact render={(props) => <Home {...props} dimensions={dimensions} />} />
          <Route
            path="/projects"
            exact
            render={(props) => <Projects {...props} dimensions={dimensions} />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/approach"
            exact
            render={(props) => <Approach {...props} dimensions={dimensions} />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/services"
            exact
            render={(props) => <Services {...props} dimensions={dimensions} />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/about-us"
            exact
            render={(props) => <About {...props} dimensions={dimensions} />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/:id"
            render={(props) => <SingleProject {...props} dimensions={dimensions} />}
          />
        </Switch>
      </div>
      <Navigation />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'll refactor to make it less repetitive but here's how i've fixed it for now.